# Is there any more efficient to update the database value?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, web

```
function updateQty($qty, $kode) {
    for ($i=0; $i <$qty ; $i++) { 
        $this->db->set('qty', 'qty+1',FALSE); 
        $this->db->where(array('kode'=>$kode, 'username'=>$this->session->userdata('username')));
        $this->db->update('temp'); 
    }
}
```

Is there an efficient way to update the `qty` column to `qty+$qty` ?
I've tried to change `qty+$qty` but it's not working.

NB :

`qty` is the column name from the database

`$qty` is the variable name in PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running a query within a loop is usually not a good idea. Instead, you can set the new value to `qty + $qty` by concatenating the variable to the string.

```
function updateQty($qty, $kode) {
    $this->db->set('qty', 'qty + '.(int)$qty); 
    $this->db->where(['kode' => $kode, 'username' = >$this->session->userdata('username')]);
    $this->db->update('temp'); 
}
```